# JS : setTimeout is throttled by Chrome browser when minimizing the browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to fire a Bosh request for every 100ms using setTimeout.It is working fine when the Tab is active.

But it is not working when minimizing the tab. Instead, it is firing the request every 1min.

Chrome is throttling the setTimeout function.

Is there any way to resolve this? I want to overcome this chrome behavior.

Here I am using Strophe.js.The setTimeout function is called by strophe.js file

Comment: Broadly, no. Chrome would have you reconsider whether you really need to do anything that often if the tab is minimized.

Comment: Why do you need to send a request every 100ms to begin with? Maybe there are more suitable solutions than using a timeout/interval?

Comment: @Ivar Actually this 100ms is for making the user alive to notify to end server using XMPP It is called strophe.js.(This is third party js, not my js)

I am using a BOSH connection to work on this.

Answer (score 0):

First, I wanted to ask why you are not using setInterval for this task because as far as I understood, you want to fire it every 100ms right?

Second, there is not really a workaround because it is standard browser behavior to prevent high CPU usage from inactive browser tabs.

Google actually posted a blog post about it which you can find
here =>
https://developer.chrome.com/blog/timer-throttling-in-chrome-88/

This got implemented in Chrome V88

They also mentioned a few techniques to work with this behavior more accurately.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I already took a look. I want to make this on the code side.Not browser configuration